# SQL Server with account NT Service\MSSQLSERVER can't access to nas

Tags: sql, backup, nas

How grant NT Service\MSSQLSERVER account to use nas as direct backup device?

Comment: You mean you want to do back ups in network drive ?

Comment: If you have a windows account that can access the NAS, start the windows service with that account.  Make sure you map a drive letter to the NAS, SQL often doesn't like UNC paths.

Comment: Why not back up locally and move the file to your NAS afterwards?
At least if the NAS isn't accessible you'll still have a useful backup!